# Copy all files from past 6 months and preserve directory structure (Linux)

Tags: linux, backup, find, copy

I have a folder on a Linux machine that I want to copy for backup purposes. Since it got too large lately, I only want to copy the files that have changed in the past 6 months, but preserve the full directory structure.

What I want to achieve is the result of

```
copy -rp folder backup/
find backup/ -mtime +180 -type f -delete
```

But I'd like to do it without first copying 20 GB of data only to delete 95% just a moment later.

So far I came up with

```
find folder/ -mtime -180 -type f -exec cp -p {} folder/ \;
```

But this doesn't preserve the directory structure...

Comment: Something like `find … -print0 | rsync --files-from=- --from0 …`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87022/108618). Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your
[cp command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)
is almost correct. You're only missing one parameter:

```
--parents
    use full source file name under DIRECTORY
```

The command should look like:

```
find folder/ -mtime -180 -type f -exec cp -p --parents '{}' folder/ \;
```